# How can I perform a click without moving the mouse in python?

Tags: python, automation, instance, pyautogui, bluestacks

I am trying to make a program that can control the mouse to perform actions in an instance of bluestacks (for those who aren't familiar with bluestacks, an instance of bluestacks is basically a second open bluestacks that can run as the same time as another bluestacks instance). I managed to get the script working with PyAutoGUI but I am forced to use the MoveTo command that moves the mouse to an X,Y position. 
My issue is that when trying to run multiple instances & scripts at once, if a click from different scripts at the same time within a short range of time, one of the clicks "bugs out" or simply doesn't happen, which stalls one of the instance scripts until I manually restart it. 
Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can make the script "click" in a position of the screen without the mouse actually moving?

EDIT: I am aware of PyAutoIt but do not believe it would work since I am running multiple instances of the same program and not different programs

Comment: Arent there two functions, one that moves the mouses and clicks, and one that instant clicks on position given.

Comment: Actually I checked the https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html docs for pyautogui, and there is a pyautogui.click(x=100, y=200) function, but it "# move to 100, 200, then click the left mouse button.", which is the issue, it moves and then clicks, not exactly just a click

Comment: You can't make a click without actually moving your mouse to the button. The instant move to the button is the minimum.

Comment: Hm ok, i'll see how I can do this then. Do you know if it's possible to run multiple keydowns at the same time with pyautogui? For example, if I select an instance, run keydown("a") (to walk left) and then select another instance and also run a keydown("a"); would the second keydown cancel the first?

Comment: Can't you chain them? Maybe work with some kind of callback? Call the second click after the first. Maybe create a function that accepts a list of clicks and executes those one after another? But I think this behaviour is not implemented in the module itself. NOTE: I only used pyautogui once to make a bot that plays poker, so multiple fast clicks weren't a problem for me.

Comment: I see, I will look into that a bit more deeply. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can also use win32 api and win32con in this type of use: x = 
        y = 
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

Comment: Tried using win32api.mouse_event, it's actually very fast but also moves the mouse around before actually performing the click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to install Android debug bridge (ADB) on your system then enable ADB debugging for each Bluestacks instance. Now you can use ADB to send commands directly to the exact emulator of your choice and you can do it in parallel because all commands are guaranteed to run on the specified device via the device ID.

`adb -s <deivce_id> shell input tap x y` where x & y are the coordinates on the screen.

You can, also, do the same thing with Appium but it will still require ADB and will be more involved - however, if you are looking to build something more than just a simple script you should really be looking at Appium.

There is a whole lot more you can do with ADB - I have a [comprehensive ADB tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wMlCucwGvE) as well if you wonder what sort of stuff you can do with it other then clicking in on x, y cords.

I also have very comprehensive tutorial playlists for Appium from [beginner](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK7KNOA7vbPNyT-9Zo0ij-iKDCQq7A0BM) to [advanced framework design](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK7KNOA7vbPOh_2sx4aKnU0y6DDUFtQaW).